# Android Glance appWidget: how to update content when user places it on screen?

Tags: android, kotlin, glance-appwidget

In my case there is no button "Refresh" data in my widget UI. From what event can widget be updated when user just place it on screen?
I tried to use method onEnabled of GlanceAppWidgetReceiver, but it is not fired. I need some event where I can run my update method.

Please, help.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, setup and first time data loading can be done in `provideGlance()`.  Beyond that, new data can be pushed to the widget when your app is running. If your widget needs to refresh its content periodically, consider using `WorkManager` to schedule updates.

To actually do the update, run `MyAppWidget().update(context, glanceId)`

More details about updating widgets can be found here https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/glance/glance-app-widget